# how to convert return type of method within when().thenReturn method of Mockito

Tags: mockito, environment-variables, junit4

Below is my code snippet. This is giving me compilation error, as `env.getProperty` will return String. How do I get integer value. `Interger.ParseInt` is not working.

```
when(this.env.getProperty("NeededIntegerValue")).thenReturn(15);
```

Below is my test class
public class MyclassTest {

```
Myclass myObj=new Myclass();
@Mock Environment env=Mockito.mock(Environment.class);

    @Before
    public void init() {       
        when(this.env.getProperty("StringKey1")).thenReturn("Stringvalue");
        when(this.env.getProperty("StringKey2")).thenReturn(intValue); 
        myObj.setEnvironment(this.env);
    }
    @Test
    public void testTenantIdentifierCutomerTypeCUSTOMER_ACCOUNT() {

        assertEquals("Expecteddata",myObj.testMethod(new StringBuilder(inputData),anotherData).toString); 

    }   
}
```

Below is the Method needs to be tested

```
public StringBuilder testMethod(StringBuilder inputData, String anotherData) 
{
    if (anotherData.equals(env.getProperty("StringKey1"))) {
        inputData=inputData.append(","+arrayOfInputData[Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("intValue"))]);
    }
}
```

Comment: by mocking `this.env` you mocking Test class object itself. Are you sure you want to achieve this. Can you please provide complete test class code?

Comment: I have added my code snippet. I am not pretty sure whether I need (this.env.getProperties) or (env.getProperties). Both are giving me the results.

Comment: so your question is about how can you mock `intValue`? If this is the case, then just pass String representation of desired int there

Comment: I have tried that it is not happening. I am getting NullPointerException while calling testMethod.

Comment: Besides all you've missed '@InjectMocks annotation

Answer (score 1):

First, you should mock your `env`, this way:

```
when(this.env.getProperty("StringKey1")).thenReturn("StringValue");
when(this.env.getProperty("StringKey2")).thenReturn("StringRepresentationOfYourInt");
```

Second, pay attention to the method itself, should be

`arrayOfInputData[Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("StringKey2"))`

not

`arrayOfInputData[Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("intValue"))`

Instead of
`myObj.setEnvironment(this.env);` in `init()` method try:

```
@InjectMocks
Myclass myObj = new Myclass();
```

Also remove assignment for

`@Mock Environment env=Mockito.mock(Environment.class);`

it should look

`@Mock Environment env;`

Comment: It is not giving me the solution. I need workaround to put integer value from my env.getProperties .

Comment: to put integer value where? can you please make your question more clear